# Get locale to controller variable

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I have `AuthController` here, where you can see it has some variables in it. I'm using them as paths after operation.

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
    private $loginPath = "authenticate";
    protected $redirectPath = "/";
}
```

The problem is I'm using Laravel localization, after login, registration operations, it returns to sites default locale. For example if I was in `www.mysite.com/de/authenticate`, after login operation I'm in `www.mysite.com/en`.
I tried to put a method in it, like `$loginPath = App::getLocale()."/authenticate";` but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [standard configuration](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L55) this should work:

```
$locale = config('app.locale');
```